# Cannot merge branch into master nor checkout

Tags: git

I have the following three branches in my local git repo:

```
$ git branch
  all_athors_&_views
* master
  third_requirement
```

When I try to merge "all_athors_&_views" into "master", it shows the following error:

```
$ git merge all_athors_&_views
[1] 27637
-bash: _views: command not found
merge: all_athors_ - not something we can merge
[1]+  Exit 1                  git merge all_athors_
```

When I try to checkout "all_athors_&_views", it shows the following error:

```
$ git checkout all_athors_&_views
[1] 27648
-bash: _views: command not found
error: pathspec 'all_athors_' did not match any file(s) known to git.
[1]+  Exit 1                  git checkout all_athors_
```

It successfully checkouts between "master" and "third_requirement".
It is the first time I run into this problem and haven't been able to figure it out. I have to mention that the file is shared  with a virtual machine via a vagrant directory (not sure if this information is helpful).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping the branch names in quotes:

```
git "merge all_athors_&_views"
```

The error message you are getting:

> -bash: _views: command not found

seems to imply that the shell is intepreting `git merge all_athors_` as one command, and the ampersand as a connector to another command `_views`.  For future reference, you might want to avoid using ampersand in your branch names.

Here is a link to some Git [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-check-ref-format.html) which discusses which characters cannot appear unescaped in a branch name.  Incidentally, your particular problem appears to be a shell, rather than a Git, thing.